# Create an object before calling the save method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create an object in Django before calling the save method. This object will be created from a ForeignKey Value, I've changed the foreignkey field to look like an input field in order to write a value instead of selecting it.

I have 2 classes in 2 different model files

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title, verbose_name="Title")
```

and

```
class Title(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", primary_key=True, max_length=200)
```

When I create a category, I have to pick or write a title that already exists in the database and when I try to create a category with a new title I get this error :

```
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.
```

What I want to do is creating a title based on what I write in the ForeignKey field before creating the category so it can be used immediately.

I tried to redefine the save method to save the title object before saving the category but it didn't work.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should probably consider putting the code to create Category entries in the model's manager:

```
class CategoryManager(Manager):
    def create_category(category, title):
        t = Title.objects.get_or_create(title=title)
        return self.create(title=t)

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title, verbose_name="Title")
    objects = CategoryManager()
```

Then use create_category every time you want to create a Category.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where should I call the create_category method? and how to set its attributes?

Comment: Call create_category from your view after you have validated the form data, like this: create_category("a new category", "a new or existing title"). Did I undestand your question correctly?

Comment: I want to do that in the admin form. The title should be created before the category so it can use it. I tried to override the pre_save signal and create a title that I use when I save the category but I didn't work. I think that the ForeignKey check happens before sending the pre_save signal. There is a way to change that or to disable ForeignKey verification? Thank you

Comment: Ok, in that case you might consider to redesign your models. If what you want is to assign a title to a category and be able to reuse the title model, you can make the title point to the category instead, using the contenttypes framework and generic inlines for the admin. I have written an (untested) example here: http://pastebin.com/kwDe3WNf. Also see documentation http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline.

Comment: Thank you very much. please check the answer below, I've explained in detail what I want

Comment: What about using a *CharField* for *Category.title* instead of a *ForeignKey*? That way Django won't validate whether a *Title* exists with that name, and you can still create it in a save hook. AFAIK this shouldn't give any big difference in the database table scheme for *Category*.

Answer (score 1):

The save is performed after the form validation, you can make the category obj creation during the validation.

Have a look at the form fields' clean methods that you can override on django docs http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: Form validation is not the appropriate place to be creating models.

Comment: @Ignacio please suggest a better alternative for this situation

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your code, I've just tested it. But it's not exactly what I'm looking for, I will explain what I want to do.

Let's say that we have Category and Article classes in our model, each one has a title. To make this title reusable, I created another application that will manage fields, I created the class Title and I added it as foreignkey to Category and Article forms.

I switched the select box to an input field using raw_id_fields.

Now, when I create a category or an article, I have to select or write a title, when this title exists, it works perfectly but when it doesn't exist I want to create it before creating the category so it can use it.

I tried to do that in the save method, in the pre_save signal and in the clean method but I always get the error "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."

I'm using a hard coded solution to create the title now, I want just to see if it will work, these are the lines that I inserted in the different methods to create the title before creating the category :

```
t = Title(title = "MyTitle")
t.save()
```

I tried to create a Category with MyTitle as title but I get the same error, when I try to create another one using an existing title, it works and the title "MyTitle" is created. That's mean that the creation of the object happens after the form verification. What I want is just doing this before. The title object should be created before the verification.

Thank you very much for your help